# Is it possible to open custom list in MS project file?

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I have custom list with some fields. Is possible to open custom list in MS Project?

I am trying to open a list in "Open with Project" option. But it looks like it is disabled. How to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade your SPD to 2013 and also upgrade OFFICE to 2013.

Comment: My SPD is 2013 and OFFICE also 2013